# Security practices for SQL Server & C# with limited database access

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, security

I have a project that I am working on that is essentially a self service database restoration / backup tool for client machines that run a database locally on their machines and contain sensitive information. Due to the nature of the business, and the amount of clients we have I simply cannot create stored procedures to use on the database with the program I am creating.

I am aware that using raw SQL statements in string format is highly susceptible to injection attacks. But with limited access to a database (essentially just to restore and back-up the database) I am asking what is the most effective and secure method to run these commands without compromising security?

Clients would simply choose the option "restore" or "backup" and the backup would only create a full copy-only backup of the database. The file location for both the backup and the restore would be set in the code an be unmodifiable.

Comment: What exactly are you backing up?  The table structure?  Just the row data?  Why can't you trigger a normal database backup and encrypt that backup accordingly?

Comment: They would just be full copy-only backups of the database.

Comment: For a backup / restore where would you  be passing text from the user?

Comment: Using strings is only insecure if you're building the strings with user specified values. From your description it doesn't sound like you are so I don't believe there are any security implications.

Comment: The only input that the user would pass is the location of where the backup would be saved. Is it possible for an injection attack to occur through manipulation of folder data? (e.g. renaming a folder to be a SQL command)

Comment: It's not really clear to me how you are doing this, but in general I think any query that is not parameterized is subject to SQL injection.

Comment: I think you need to post some code, or at least pseudo-code, to clarify what you are really doing.

Comment: Yes if you are receiving text from the user and then executing that text against your server you are vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just use a [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296201(v=sql.105).aspx)